# JavaScript is not working on Windows Mobile and Windows Phone

Tags: javascript, windows-phone-7, jquery-mobile, windows-mobile

I wrote one hybrid application by using jQuery mobile. It is working on Android and iPhone, but on Windows Phone the UI is coming up, but the JavaScript functions are not working.

This is my code:

```
<html >
    <head>
           <script type="text/javascript">
            function  checkUser(){

                //here is my logic to to next screen
                         }
       </script>
   </head>
   <body>
     <div data-role="page" data-theme="b" id="page1">
          <p>
     <a data-role="button" data-transition="none" data-theme="e" onclick="checkUser(); "  rel="external"> Login </a>
          </p>
     </div>
   </body>
</html>
```

When I click the login button the `checkUser` function is not being called. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I'm assuming you are using a WebBrowser control. If so you can use the InvokeScript method to execute JavaScript. Reference: <a href="http://blogs.msdn.com/b/mikeormond/archive/2010/08/26/calling-javascript-functions-in-windows-phone-7.aspx">Calling JavaScript Functions in Windows Phone 7</a>

Comment: If you are using the `WebBrowser` component and passing your html to that component make sure you enable the script. `<WebBrowser IsScriptEnabled = true />`

Comment: I have done this <WebBrowser IsScriptEnabled = true />. But it does not work.

Answer (score 0):

You should have an `href` in there.  For example: `<a href="#" onclick="someFunction()">`

Comment: Correct @adam this may be cause of problem.

Comment: or better: return someFunction() where someFunction returns false

Comment: I updated like follows.but still not calling

<a href="#" data-role="button" data-transition="none" data-theme="e" onclick="checkUser(); "  rel="external"> Login </a>

Answer (score 0):

You have a good opportunity to use unobtrusive JS - even more so since you use jQuery:

```
<html >
  <head>
    <script... jquery...></script>
       <script type="text/javascript">
          $(function() {
            $("#page1 a").on("click",function() {
              //here is my logic to to next screen
              return false; // or e.preventDefault()
            });
          });
   </script>
 </head>
 <body>
 <div data-role="page" data-theme="b" id="page1">
      <p>
 <a href="#" data-role="button" data-transition="none" data-theme="e" rel="external"> Login </a>
      </p>
 </div>
 </body>
 </html>
```

Comment: I am trying to use like follows.
<html >
 <head>
  
   <script type="text/javascript">
    $(function() {
    $("#page1 a").on("click",function() {
    //here is my logic to to next screen
    alert("Please provide user name");
    navigator.notification.alert("Hi");

    return false; // or e.preventDefault()
    });
    });
   </script>
  </head>
 <body>
  <div data-role="page" data-theme="b" id="page1">
   <p>
    <a href="#" data-role="button" data-transition="none" data-theme="e" rel="external"> Login </a>
   </p>
  </div>
 </body>
</html>
But still function is not calling.

Answer (score 0):

unfortunately, Windows Mobile 6 and possibly Windows phone browsers do not support full javascript standard. For example, before Windows Mobile 6.1.4 (AKU version levlel) there was no onKey... javascript support. To see if there is something that WinodwsMobile Internet Explorer Mobile (IEM) does not support, enable ShowScriptErrors:

```
// If you want Pocket IE to display script errors set this registry key:
// [HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\Main] "ShowScriptErrors"=dword:00000001
// MSDN Knowledge Base Q306520
// Recommended !!
```

see also http://forum.gpsgate.com/pop_printer_friendly.asp?TOPIC_ID=1499

I dont know, how far JQuery is supported on WM, but the following is a working code snippet to call a javascript function for a button click:

```
<input type="button" style="width:90" name="pushbutton_0" value=" F2-Zrks" onfocus="javascript:doOnFocus(0);" onclick="javascript:doSubmit(0);">
```

~josef

Answer (score 0):

I have created a new project using html template of VS Express 2012 for Windows Phone.

As recommended by "nkchandra", I needed to enable Javascript (see `IsScriptEnabled` ) in file MainPage.xaml :

```
<Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot" Background="Transparent">
    <phone:WebBrowser x:Name="Browser"
                      HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
                      VerticalAlignment="Stretch"
                      Loaded="Browser_Loaded"
                      IsScriptEnabled = "True"
                      NavigationFailed="Browser_NavigationFailed" />
</Grid>
```